# Save Lambda's Progress if something went wrong

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, geopy

I'm trying to use geopy on a list of addresses with `pandas` and `lambda`, but if connection is lost I'll lose all the progress, is there a way to somehow save it so if something went wrong in the middle of the procedure I can just continue from where I've stopped?
that's the line I'm using, it's a very basic line

```
df.output = df.Address.apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x,timeout=30,language="en")).apply(lambda x: x.raw))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. There's plenty of examples for iterrows, iteritems, itertuples. Without knowing the goelocator function or how it works, you may have to tweak this.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    gcode = geolocator.geocode(row['Address'],timeout=30,language="en")
    row['output'] = gcode.raw
```

Comment: Can you show an example, please? I have a tendency to screw things up